# Compare two list of objects C#

Tags: c#, list

I want to compare two list of objects. These lists contains the same type of objects. I create a new List in my programme and i want to compare it at the old list which is in the database. I get it with a stored procedure, then i put it into an object.

```
The old list :                     the new list :

*Category 1*                         Category 5
*Category 2*                         Category 6
*Category 3*                         *Category 4*  
Category 4
```

Here the aim is to **delete the first three Category in the old list**, beacause they don't exist in the new list. And to **delete the Category 4 in the  new list** because category 4 already exists in the old list.

It is possible to use à method like `Equals()` or use two `foreach` loop to browse the lists ?

Thanks for you answers and advises

Comment: have you tried `.Except()` extension method?

Comment: I've tried that but, the problem is that i don't use all properties of the object and it don't work. It is possible to choose the properties to compare ?

Comment: The Except() method can take an IEqualityComparer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132151%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which you must implement. It should perform the comparison you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the linq, `except` and `where`

```
var a = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var b = new List<string> { "c", "d", "e" };
var temp = a.Intersect(b).ToList();
b = b.Except(a).ToList();
a = temp;
```

Output:

```
a: "c"
b: "d", "e"
```

Note: It is probably more efficient to do this without linq

```
var a = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var b = new List<string> { "c", "d", "e" };

for(int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
    if(b.Contains(a[i]))
        b.Remove(a[i]);
    else
        a.Remove(a[i--]);
```

If you need to compare based on a particular value

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
{
    var obj = b.Where(item => item.Category == a[i].Category);
    if(obj.Any())
        b.Remove(obj.First());
    else
        a.Remove(a[i--]);
}
```

Comment: You could use `Intersect` instead of the `Where`/`Contains` combo. For example: `var temp = a.Intersect(b).ToList();`

Comment: @LukeH - Thanks, I forgot about `Intersect`

Comment: That's a good idea it works fine, but i've anonther problem it's that the objects properties are not the same. For instance i've Title = Category1, Id = 2 , rank = 4, and the other Title = Category1, Id = 2, rank = 0. Because of Rank it don't match. I think that i will fix the problem of the rank putting it to zero all time !

Comment: @Julien698 - I've updated the question with a resolution to that, I haven't updated the linq version because I still think the bottom code will be faster

Comment: The code without Linq is `O(n^2)` since `List(T).Remove` is `O(n)` as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx As such you would be much better off creating two new lists setting the length to n and then

Comment: @Seph - True, if the list(s) contains many elements then it may be worthwhile just creating new lists

Comment: it's working, but at the output i obtain : a: "a","b","c" and b: "c". It's not a problem now i can do : "listInput b - output b" to get only "d" and "e". For a the same to get "a","b"

Comment: @Julien698 - That looks to be the exact opposite of what you are after, how are you using this? I updated not long ago with an updated example using a property

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most pretty of implementations but the fastest way you can do this is:

```
var tempA = new HashSet<int>(inputA.Select(item => item.Id));
var tempB = new HashSet<int>(inputB.Select(item => item.Id));

var resultA = new List<Category>(inputA.Count);
var resultB = new List<Category>(inputB.Count);

foreach (var value in inputA)
    if (tempB.Contains(value.Id))
        resultA.Add(value);

foreach (var value in inputB)
    if (!tempA.Contains(value.Id))
        resultB.Add(value);

resultA.TrimExcess();
resultB.TrimExcess();

// and if needed:
inputA = resultA;
inputB = resultB;
```

If you need more than item.id as unique then use a new Tuple such as:

```
inputA.Select(item => new Tuple<int, string>(item.Id, item.Title));
```

Another option is to override .GetHashCode in your category class such as:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Id.GetHashCode();
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var typedObj = obj as Category;
    if (typedObj == null)
        return false;
    return Title == typedObj.Title && Id == typedObj.Id && Rank == typedObj.Rank;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by sorting the two list and iterating over the first and second list. I would compare the current item of the first list to the current item from the second. If a match is found I remove the match from the second list and I move to the next item in both lists, otherwise the current item of the first list is removed from it and the iteration continues in the first list.

Comment: What makes you think they are sortable?